# looking for an explanation of .NET DataTable events and handling

Tags: .net, c++, events, datatable

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around `.NET DataTable` events, handling, actions, etc.

I have attempted to understand from the MSDN library, but I find I haven't got an understanding of how it all works together. I also haven't been able to find any other source (by googling) that explains the ins and outs of it.

For example, I'm trying to understand that there are `DataTable` events (such as `ColumnChanged`, `RowChanged`, etc.) but there are also `DataRowColumnChangeEventArgs`, `DataColumnChangeEventArgs`, etc. How do they relate/work together?

Can anyone provide a link that provides a thorough explanation of `DataTable` events and handling? (Or provide one yourself if you have that kind of time lol!) (Hoping for examples in `C++` in particular, but if in another language I can make do for now)

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're getting confused between the events themselves and the EventArgs parameters that get passed to your actual event handler.

When you register to handle an event, there are a couple of things you have to know. I'll use your `ColumnChanged` event as an example.

The first is that the Event you're registering for is the `ColumnChanged` event (seems straight forward, but I included it for clarities sake).

The second is that to register for an event, you need an event handler. That event handler has to match the delegate signature provided by the event. In the case of ColumnChanged, the delegate must take two parameters: 1) an object called sender and 2) an object used to pass event specific arguments called `DataColumnChangedEventArgs`. Your method should look something like:

```
public void ColumnChangedHandler(object sender, DataColumnChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do some work here when the event is fired
}
```

After you have that, the last step is actually registering your handler to handle the event:

```
someDataTable.ColumnChanged += 
    new DataColumnChangeEventHandler(ColumnChangedHandler);
```

Now, if you look around you'll  probably notice that some people use shortcut syntax to create a handler all in one step:

```
someDataTable.ColumnChanged += (object sender, DataColumnChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do some work here when the event is fired
    }
```

That will allow you to create an anonymous method to handle the event, but could cause problems when it comes time to clean up the object and un-register any handlers.

Comment: I agree with Justin.  It looks to me as though you're confusing the event (e.g.: RowChanged) with arguments passed to those events (e.g.: DataRowChangedEventArgs).  One's the event, the other is arguments passed to the event.

Comment: @Rod: Yes.. I need more of an article explaining their "roles" in the event handling though. I realize they are different, but I'm new to event handling and I'm really trying to understand the ins and outs of it.

Comment: Your lengthier answer helps more (I commented before when you had your first draft up). Thanks :) I still need a bit more of a description; know of any great links that might go into a bit more depth?

Comment: So I'm not sure if I should mark this as the answer, it helps me partially, but I'm looking for a link that can provide the full picture of .NET DataTable event handling that is better explained than MSDN.

Comment: I find these examples on MSDN quite good: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9a401.aspx